# Reading numeric data through a text file and storing into a variable

Tags: c++, file

This is my code so far. It reads to the file every time, but the output looks like this :

```
-92559631349317830736831783200707727132248687965119994463780864.000000
```

for both values read. I just recently changed the variable from `float` to a `double`. I realize I have unused variables and such, this isn't even the whole code yet. If I could get help enough to be displaying the proper values in a cout statement, it would be much appreciated. What do i need to do with my `inUserAccount` statement?

I've checked a lot of sources on here so far and nothing uses the same code as we've learned so far, or what's in our book. The file we're reading to looks like this:

```
4567.89

15.98
```

one is a checking account, the other a savings.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

fstream inUserAccount;
double checkingBalance, savingsBalance;
char ChkorSav, option, yesorNo;
int  count=0;
bool validInput=true ;

while (validInput = true) {     // my loop for the whole ATM cycle
    cout << "Welcome to your ATM!\nPlease choose from the options below:\n"
        << "1:Deposit\n2:Withdraw\n3:Balance Inquiry\n4:Transfer Money\n";

    setprecision(2);

    while (validInput) {
        cin >> option;
        if (option == '1' || option == '2' || option == '3' || option == '4')
            validInput = false;

        else cout << "Please enter a valid option. \n";

        if (validInput == true && count >= 3)
            cout << "(Enter the corresponding number to the option you desire) \n";
        count++;
    }
    count = 0;          // resetting my loop variables
    validInput = true;


        inUserAccount.open("lab5data.txt");
        double savings, checking;
        inUserAccount >> fixed >> savings >> checking;
        cout << fixed << savings << endl << checking;
```

Comment: Code in question is all the way at bottom, and declaration is near the top. Thanks again

Comment: Is your question about reading a file having different lines of numerical values (Account and savings) and converting it into a double?

Comment: i need to store the first numerical value into one variable, and the next in another. The lab is an ATM simulator so i will add, subtract, transfer amounts to and from the values accordingly, i just need to read the data properly first

Comment: i guess to answer your question directly, yes. It will only ever need to read the 2 lines though

Comment: If it's about "transfer money" - I would never count money with `double` as financial guys usually insist on absolute precision... (Instead, I would count cents and insert a decimal point before the last two digits to express $s or whatever is the superior over cents.)

Comment: You need to check the result of every input operation and report any errors. The other methods known as "guessing" and "praying" have been proven unreliable. `inUserAccount.open("lab5data.txt");` Did it work? Who knows. `inUserAccount >> fixed >> savings >> checking;` Did it work? Who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question is to read a file with numerical values inside different lines to be assigned to `double`s...

**Use this magic function:**

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> read_stream(std::ifstream& stream)
{
    std::vector<std::string> numerical_strings;               // A vector which stores all the lines...
    std::stringstream ss;                                     // Creating a string stream...
    ss << stream.rdbuf();                                     // Reading the contents of file into the string stream...
    std::string temporary;                                    // A temporary string that iterates over all lines...
    while (std::getline(ss, temporary, '\n'))                 // Looping over all lines...
        if (!temporary.empty())                               // We will only push it inside the vector if the line is not empty...
            numerical_strings.emplace_back(temporary);        // Push line inside the vector...
    std::vector<T> numbers;                                   // A vector of "numbers" of type you want...
    for (auto & elem : numerical_strings)                     // Iterate over the string vector...
    {
        auto temp_number = T(strtold(elem.c_str(), nullptr)); // Your usual conversion function...
        if (errno == ERANGE)                                  // Checking for errors...
            continue;                                         // If the line is alpha numeric or something like that, skip it...
        numbers.emplace_back(temp_number);                    // If the line is a valid number, push it inside the vector...
    }
    return numbers;                                           // Return the vector of the numbers of arbitrary type...
}
```

---

**An example to demonstrate its usage:**

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream some_file("account_file.txt");
    auto a = read_stream<long double>(some_file);
    for (auto b : a) // It will iterate through all the numeric lines, not just the first two...
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> **Output:**
>   4567.89
>   15.98

---

> **Note:** For your problem, you only want the first two elements of the vector... So just check if it is empty using `a.empty()` and take the first number with `a[0]` and second number with `a[1]`...

---

> **Also, make sure you have these includes at the top:**
>
> ```
> #include <fstream>
> #include <sstream>
> #include <iomanip>
> ```

Kind regards,

Ruks.

Comment: thank you very much! huge help, so much appreciated!

Comment: In that case, You should show consideration by [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)...

Comment: Way, way overkill for reading values from a file. `_errno` is undeclared. A simple `while ((inUserAccount >> savings >> checking)) { /* use savings, checking */ }` should suffice.

Comment: The *>>operator* is widely known for eating whitespaces and if there is any spaces or tabs between the numbers in any line... It would divide that as well... `*_errno()` is the macro replacement for the `errno` macro... Also, we can't just go on directly doing `inUserAccount >> savings >> checking`... What if the line is empty, what if the received word is not a number... We may never know what number it might assign to those variables in these cases...